# converting Big endian to little endian in c. warning:return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] return src;

Tags: c, pointers, bitmap, endianness

The purpose of  function `convertEndian()` is to convert big endian to little endian

> warning:return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]          return src;

problem is about return types, one of them is `char **` the other is `char *`

I need `char **` in order to swap but again i need return type as `char *`. so do you have any suggestion?

```
char *convertEndian(void *source)
{
    typedef unsigned char EightBytes[8];

    unsigned char temp;
    //  char **src = (char **)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char *));
    //  char *temp = (char *)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));

    EightBytes *src = (EightBytes *)source;
    temp = (*src)[0];
    (*src)[0] = (*src)[7];
    (*src)[7] = temp;

    temp = (*src)[1];
    (*src)[1] = (*src)[6];
    (*src)[6] = temp;

    temp = (*src)[2];
    (*src)[2] = (*src)[5];
    (*src)[5] = temp;

    temp = (*src)[3];
    (*src)[3] = (*src)[4];
    (*src)[4] = temp;

    return src;  //shows warning for this part
}

//convertEndian function will be used inside this function
int getHeaderSize(unsigned char * header)
{
    char * headerSize = (char *)malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)
    {
        headerSize[i] = header[i + 20];
        headerSize[i + 1] = header[i + 21];
    }
    headerSize[8]  = '\0';
    headerSize = convertEndian(headerSize);
    int size = hex2int(headerSize);
    return size;    
}
```

Comment: You're trying to return a pointer to an array of unsigned char from a function defined as returning a pointer to a char.

Comment: The warning message is 100% correct--you declare the function to return a `char *`, but you're actually returning a `char **`.

Comment: Also, you could use `htonl()` instead.

Comment: Actually, @LeeDanielCrocker, the extended error from GCC 9.2.0 says `error: returning ‘unsigned char (*)[8]’ from a function with incompatible return type ‘char *’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]`.  It's attempting to return a pointer to an array of 8 `unsigned char` instead of a `char *`.

Comment: so,could you please provide me with the correct version?although I understand the reason of the problem,still can't handle the problem . i need char ** in order to swap but again i need return type as char *. so what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I can be bothered to work out what storage (mis)management is going on in the code in the question.  A much simpler way of doing the job is:

```
extern void *convertEndian(void *source);

void *convertEndian(void *source)
{
    char *src = source;

    for (int i = 0, j = 7; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        char tmp[1];
        tmp[0] = src[i];
        src[i] = src[j];
        src[j] = tmp[0];
    }
    return source;
}
```

The use of an array for `tmp` is aconventional but makes the 'swap block' of assignments uniformly aligned for three lines; you could perfectly well write:

```
extern void *convertEndian(void *source);

void *convertEndian(void *source)
{
    char *src = source;

    for (int i = 0, j = 7; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        char tmp = src[i];
        src[i] = src[j];
        src[j] = tmp;
    }
    return source;
}
```

It's unlikely that the code generated is any different whichever notation you use.

If you wish to manually unwrap the loop instead of relying on the compiler to optimize, then that's your prerogative.

If you insist on returning a `char *`, then change the return type from `void *` to `char *` — no other changes are required (though you could write `return src;` if you really wanted to).

You could use any 8-bit integer type in place of `char` — so `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `int8_t` or `uint8_t` could all be used instead with essentially no difference.  I'm ignoring the possibility of `CHAR_BITS > 8`; if that's a problem for you, there's rethinking to be done.  If you used `return src;` and the type of `src` doesn't match the return type of the function, then you have to cast it, or revert to `return source;`.

Comment: Hmmm, on those non-existent non-2's complement machines with signed `char`, can `tmp[0] = src[i];` fold  a +0 and -0 into the same zero (or trigger a trap)?  Of course using `unsigned char` rather than `char` avoids this niche concern.  Just looking for your take on that.

Comment: I would expect that on machines with signed zeros, assigning a signed zero would copy the sign, but I’ve no actual experience with such machines and I might be mistaken. This is different from comparing signed zeros.